# What to do when my requests for feedback are denied?

Tags: feedback

As a medical resident, feedback is crucial for personal development. In my experience, the attending is often too busy to provide feedback on a patient interaction, even when I explicitly ask for it. Does anyone have any suggestions/strategies/tips on what I can do to get ANY feedback when my request is turned down?

Comment: Do your fellow residents experience the same problem? If that's the case maybe a well thought out discussion with the director of residents (or some such) might help. If the problem is just yours I don't know what to suggest.

Comment: I think not only for "personal" development, but _professional_, surely. :)